# Rails websocket issue on Cloud66

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, rake, cloud66

I use with tubesock gem to add websockets support to my application Rails 4. Everything works fine on the localhost, but after deploy to DigitalOcean via Cloud66 I get an error while connecting to it from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.development.c66.me/live?encoding=text' failed: Unexpected response code: 503
```

Only difference in configuration is that I use PUMA server locally and Passenger in the stack.

live_controller.rb

```
class LiveController < ApplicationController
  include Tubesock::Hijack

  def index
    hijack do |tubesock|
      tubesock.onopen do
        tubesock.send_data "Hello, stranger!"
      end

      tubesock.onmessage do |data|
        tubesock.send_data "You said: #{data}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
...
get "/live" => "live#index", as: "live"
...
```

What could be the root of this problem?

Comment: Feel free to contact support if you have any more issues with this - we'll be happy to help. Disclaimer: I work for Cloud 66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Unicorn on the production side? (http://help.cloud66.com/web-server/custom-webserver.html)

It might help as when using Unicorn the version and configuration of nginx that is deployed by Cloud 66 works with WebSockets.

Comment: That helps without load balancer. I enabled load balancer for the stack, and receive 503 again. Well, I will try to switch to Faye or something. Looks like they have good support for that thing.